# Store the score grade and mark for them in array, beginner

Tags: c#, arrays

I am beginner in c# and I don't know how  to use arrays in right way and  here is the question:

Write a program , which reads the scores of a test and according to the given score grade determines the marks of the test. store the score grade and the marks in an array and use these arrays determining the marks.Here I tried to code and what should I use for loop or smth else?

```
Console.WriteLine("Write your score : ");
        int score = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int n = 5;
        int[] vect = new int[n];
        TestResults(vect);



    }

    private static void TestResults(int [] vect)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Please try some code and show it to us. We are not a code-writing service

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets break your question down in an attempt to solve it.

> Reads the scores of a test

Simple, you could use something like `Console.ReadLine` which can take in a user input of a test grade.

```
string grade = Console.ReadLine(); // save the user input in a string
```

> Determines the mark of a test

I'll assume you mean percentage-wise. Try taking the user input, dividing it by the total of the test, and getting that value should be fine. Since `Console.ReadLine` will return a string, expect the need to convert the `string` to an `int`.

```
int mark;

if (int.TryParse(grade, out _grade))
{
    mark = (double percentage = _grade / total_of_test) * 100;
}
```

> Store the grades and marks in an array

You could write a class called `TestResults`, create 2 variables, one for the grades, and another for the marks, then add that class to an array of `TestResults[]`. This will allow you to directly call either the marks or the grade depending on what you'd prefer.

```
public class TestResults
{
    int marks;
    int grades;
}
```

I hope this was somewhat helpful. Please be mindful next time and post some code showing you have atleast tried to tackle the problem.

Edit: In terms of creating an array, lets look at an example

Here's an example of an array:

```
int[] this_int_array = new int[] { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }
```

This code will automatically get the length of the array to be 6, therefore we do not need to specify a length initially. It can be accessed by:

```
this_int_array[0] // till 5, since programming starts counting at 0.
```

In your case, something like this should work. First, lets look at our test results class. We have 2 fields, marks and grades. We can access these directly from within an instantiated field (`TestResults tr = new TestResults` is an example of instantiation. Anything being defined as a `new` is being instantiated)

```
public class TestResults
{
    int marks;
    int grades;
}
```

Then, in order to make it an array, do the following:

```
TestResult student_A = new TestResult {
                                marks = 9;
                                grades = 90; // as an example
                            }
```

then, once you've got a nice list of students, we can add them to an array.

```
TestResult[] all_results = new TestResults[] {
                                    student_A,
                                    student_B,
                                    student_C
                                }
```

I hope this was more clear.

Comment: I don't really know how to use array , here I tried to code  :            static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write your score : ");
            int score = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int n = 5;
            int[] vect = new int[n];
            TestResults(vect);



        }

        private static void TestResults(int [] vect)
        {
           
        }

Comment: I'll update my answer with an explanation and some more examples.